# Как из метода вызвать другой метод?

Tags: java, ооп

При работе с API я замечаю как интересно можно "вытащить" данные из объекта.

Допустим, я хочу узнать имя друга у человека с именем **Alex**.

Чтобы это сделать, я пишу:
`String NameOfThumb = person.getPerson("Alex").getFriends.get(0).getName();`

Как сделать так, чтобы вызывая один метод, я мог сразу вызвать внутри другой, а внутри другого следующий? Как называется такое действие?

В интернете я в основном натыкаюсь на `extends`, `implements`, но примеры, которые приводят, слишком простые и обощенные. Как я понимаю, что мне стоит использовать это, только я не знаю как именно, чтобы добиться того же результата, что я привел сверху.

*Прошу меня поправить, если я некорректно выразился и неправильно использовал терминологию.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, у вас `person` - это какой-то класс-держатель людей (я обозвал его `PersonsHandler`), а `getFriends` - не поле, а метод. Учитывая это, а также если предположить, что нулевой друг это "лучший друг", то можно так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PersonHandler personsHandler = new PersonHandler(personsHandler);
    String nameOfThumb = getBestFriendOfAlex(personsHandler);
}

private static List<Person> getPersonsFriends(PersonHandler personsHandler, String personName) {
    return personsHandler.getPerson(personName).getFriends();
}

private static Person getPersonBestFriend(PersonHandler personHandler, String personName) {
    return getPersonsFriends(personHandler, personName).get(0);
}

private static String getBestFriendOfAlex(PersonHandler personsHandler) {
    return getPersonBestFriend(personsHandler, "Alex").getName();
}

private static String getBestFriendOfJohn(PersonHandler personsHandler) {
    return getPersonBestFriend(personsHandler, "John").getName();
}
```

Класс `PersonHandler`

```
public class PersonHandler {
private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

public Person getPerson(String name) {
    return new Person(); // ищете в коллекции по имени
}
```

}

Класс `Person`

```
public class Person {
    private List<Person> friends;
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Person> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }
}
```

ну и плодить необходимые вам методы `getBestFriendOfXXX`. Можно также дальше убирать параметры из методов, создавая например `getBestFriendOfXXXFromConcretePersonHandler()` итд...
Ну и не забывать, что можем получить NPE, если не найдена особа или листы не инициализированы...

В итоге получите набор методов, отвечающий за друзей конкретного человека. Типа фабрика получается.

Answer (score 2):

Это называется [fluent interface](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) и достигается возвращением из метода того объекта, методы которого могут вызываться дальше в цепочке. Часто из методов возвращается ссылка на самого себя.

```
public class Example {
    public Example someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        return this;
    }

    public Example anotherMethod() {
        System.out.println("World");
        return this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example obj = new Example();
        obj.someMethod().anotherMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Это похоже на шаблон `Builder`, только без `.build()` в конце )))

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець да, действительно похоже. Особенно в стримах, где промежуточные операции изменяют состояние потока, а терминальная операция что-либо "строит" из этого состояния.

Comment: Но тут методы не вызываются один из другого, как хотел автор вопроса @Antonio112009

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець автор вопроса уж очень смутно объяснил свои намерения.

Answer (score 2):

Каждый метод возвращает объект, метод которого вы и вызываете в следующем звене.

Код

```
String NameOfThumb = person.getPerson("Alex").getFriends.get(0).getName();
```

аналогичен

```
Person alex = person.getPerson("Alex").
List<Person> friends = alex.getFriends();
Person alexesFriend = friends.get(0);
String name = alexesFriend.getName();
```