# Правильно написана программа работы с методом одного класса с другим?

Tags: java, ооп

Изучаю вызов метода в методе (точно термина не знаю).

Написал мини-тестовую (рабочую) программу, в которой я задаю объекту какие-то данные и вывожу их. Программа рабочая, но корректно ли она написанно или можно сделать лучше?

Интересует именно вызов метода одного класса через метод другого класса.
Так, например,  я вызываю с помощью `country.getCar()` метод класса ***CarImp.java*** - `getCountry`.

P.S. Вопрос, заданный раннее по данной теме, чтобы понять чего я хочу добиться - [ссылка на Stack](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899840/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4/899905#899905)

***MainTest.java***

```
public class MainTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Country country = new CountryImpl();

        country.getCar().setCountry("German");
        System.out.println(country.getCar().getCountry());
        System.out.println(country.getCar().getEngine());
        }

}
```

---

---

***Country.java***

```
public interface Country {
    Car getCar();
}
```

***CountryImpl.java***

```
public class CountryImpl implements Country{

    public final Car car;

    public CountryImpl() {
        this.car = new CarImpl();
    }

    @Override
    public Car getCar() {
        return car;
    }
}
```

---

---

***Car.java***

```
public interface Car {

    String getEngine();

    void setCountry(String country);    

    String getCountry();

}
```

***CarImpl.java***

```
public class CarImpl implements Car {

    String country;
    String brand;

    @Override
    public String getEngine() {
        if(country.equals("Germany"))
            return "Good engine";
        if(country.equals("Japan"))
            return "Many times better than German";
        return "Bad engine";
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    @Override
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

}
```

Comment: А что с чем должно быть связано? Почему у Вас машина - свойство страны, а не наоборот?

Comment: Страна может выпускать только одну марку машины?

Comment: @Zufir это не имеет значение. интересует только `country.getCar().getCountry()`, `country.getCar().setCountry("German")`

Почему вначале страна? А что если я напишу метод дом? То будет тогда, к примеру,  `contry.getHouses.get(0).getHouseName`

Comment: @Igor Это пример. Не более того.

Answer (score 2):

> "вызов метода одного класса через метод другого класса"

Будем четче формулировать. Что значит эта фраза?

Вы хотите сказать - "вызов метода объекта, возвращенного предыдущим методом"?

Никакой принципиальной разницы между

```
country.getCar().setCountry("Germany");
```

и

```
Car car = country.getCar();
car.setCountry("Germany");
```

нет. На мой взгляд, первый подход поощряет написание длинных неудобочитаемых цепочек вызовов. Я могу такое (с натяжкой) оправдать, когда все методы возвращают одно и то же - объект, чьи методы вызываются. Тогда читателю кода не надо на каждом шаге соображать, что же там вернулось, и чей метод теперь вызывается.

Comment: Мне немного трудно формулировать мысли на русском. Знаю это. 
Мне стало интересно узнать и понять как создаются Java-библиотеки, чтобы получать такие цепочки. Сейчас я пишу бота для Discord и использую библиотеку JDA. И там очень удобно реализовано получение каких-либо нужных тебе значений.

Comment: К примеру:
`MessageReceivedEvent event = new MessageReceivedEvent();
           int id =  event.getGuild().getMembers().get(0).getUser().getId();`