# Вызов методов друг за другом через точку

Tags: java, классы, fluent-interface

Имеется класс с методами. Код для примера:

```
package helpers;


import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;

import java.util.Date;

public class DateTimeHelper {
    /**
     * текущая дата
     */
    private static final DateTime originalDate = new DateTime(new Date());

    /**
     * получить текущую дату и время относительно запуска теста
     */
    public DateTime getOriginalDate(){
        return originalDate;
    }

    /**
     * Печать даты в требуемом формате
     * @param date дата которую надо напечатать
     * @param format формат печати
     * @return строку содержащую требуемую дату в требуемом формате
     */
    public String printDateShortFormat(DateTime date,String format){
        String pattern="yyyy";
        switch (format){
            case "standard":
                pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy' 'HH:mm";
                break;
            case "full":
                // не задаём формат
                break;
            case "only-date":
                pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy";
                break;
            case "only-time":
                pattern = "HH:mm";
                break;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError("[ERROR] Не обрабатываемый формат");
        }
        return DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).print(date);
    }

    /**
     * Прибавление к дате дней
     * @param date дата
     * @param days количество дней добавляемых к дате
     * @return результат сложения
     */
    public DateTime plusDays(DateTime date, int days){
        return date.plusDays(days);
    }    
}
```

не хочу вызывать методы вот так

```
dateTimeHelper.printDateShortFormat(
    dateTimeHelper.plusDays(dateTimeHelper.getOriginalDate(),5 ),
    "standard"
);
```

Как нужно описать данный класс, чтобы можно было вызывать методы схожим образом(псевдокод):
Как можно реализовать ситуацию где возвращается значение и следующий метод через точку принимает это значение как параметр? пример:

```
DateTimeHelper.getOriginalDate().plusDays(5).printDateShortFormat("standard")
```

так вообще можно?)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900151

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это называется [fluent interface](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) и достигается возвращением из метода того объекта, методы которого могут вызываться дальше в цепочке. Часто из методов возвращается ссылка на самого себя.

```
public class Example {
    public Example someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        return this;
    }

    public Example anotherMethod() {
        System.out.println("World");
        return this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example obj = new Example();
        obj.someMethod().anotherMethod();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class DateTimeHelper {
    private static class DateWrapper {
        private LocalDateTime dateTime;
        private DateTimeFormatter formatter;

        public DateWrapper(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
            this.dateTime = dateTime;
        }

        public DateWrapper shortFormat(String format) {
            String pattern="yyyy";
            switch (format) {
                case "standard":
                    pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy' 'HH:mm";
                    break;
                case "full":
                    // не задаём формат
                    break;
                case "only-date":
                    pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy";
                    break;
                case "only-time":
                    pattern = "HH:mm";
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Неизвестный формат");
            }
            formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
            return this;
        }

        public DateWrapper plusDays(int days) {
            dateTime = dateTime.plusDays(days);
            return this;
        }

        public void print() {
            if (formatter == null)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Не задан формат");
            System.out.println(dateTime.format(formatter));
        }
    }

    public static DateWrapper now() {
        return new DateWrapper(LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeHelper.now()
                      .plusDays(5)
                      .shortFormat("standard")
                      .print();
    }
}
```

Comment: если смотреть на пример кода что я писал в вопросе. как можно реализовать ситуацию где возвращается значение и следующий метод через точку принимает это значение как параметр?
пример: `DateTimeHelper.getOriginalDate().plusDays(5).printDateShortFormat("standard")`

Comment: Как я уже написал "достигается возвращением из метода того объекта, методы которого могут вызываться дальше в цепочке". То есть возвращать например не `LocalDate`, а какой-нибудь `LocalDateWrapper`.

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Но для этого вам нужен какой-нибудь builder, который будет в каждом методе инициализации обновлять свои поля и возвращать себя (this), а в последнем методе (в вашем случае print) возвращать форматированное значение полей, проинициализированных ранее. Советую прочитать про паттерн Builder.
Также советую присмотреться к классам LocalDate и LocalDateTime. Ваши утилитные методы (я бы сделал их статическими) очень похожи на то, что в них уже есть.